# Parse On Azure - I'm getting "Error: Unauthorized"

Tags: azure, parse-platform

When I try access e.g. **myapp.azurewebsites.net/parse** I get the error `{"error":"unauthorized"}`.

I'm not sure why as the parse web app I had previously on azure (before the trial ended - now deleted) worked fine. Since the trial has ended I have created a new web app identical to the last (different name however), using the same github deployment and app settings. I can't figure out where I've gone wrong and can't seem to find any advice online. Thanks!

Comment: Did you manage to resolve this problem if so could you post an answer so I can upvote :)

Answer (score 1):

So after digging it seems that they have configured the dashboard to be at the following url:

https://[YOURSITE].azurewebsites.net/parse-dashboard/

You can log in with your parse appid and masterkey.